# any waitForJs function to wait for some javascript code returns true

Tags: selenium, go, selenium-webdriver

This is question about [golang selenium webdriver](https://github.com/fedesog/webdriver).

Is there any function that returns only after some js code return true.

```
var session *webdriver.Session
...
session.waitForJs(`$('#redButton').css('color')=='red'`)
// next code should be executed only after `#redButton` becomes red
```

The problem is that method `session.waitForJs` do not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any wait functions in the golang bindings to Selenium, so you'll most likely need to define your own. This is my first attempt at golang, so bear with me:

```
type elementCondition func(e WebElement) bool

// Function returns once timeout has expired or the element condition is true
func (e WebElement) WaitForCondition(fn elementCondition, int timeOut) {

    // Loop if the element condition is not true
    for i:= 0; !elementCondition(e) && i < timeOut; i++ {
        time.sleep(1000)
    }
}
```

There are two options to define the `elementCondition`. Your method of using Javascript looks like it could work with the `ExecuteScript` function documented in [webdriver.go](https://github.com/fedesog/webdriver/blob/master/webdriver.go)

> // Inject a snippet of JavaScript into the page for execution in the
>   context of the currently selected frame. The executed script is
>   assumed to be synchronous and the result of evaluating the script is
>   returned to the client.

An alternative is to access the element properties through Selenium

```
func ButtonIsRed(WebElement e) (bool) {
    return (e.GetCssProperty('color') == 'red')
}
```

So your code would become

```
var session *webdriver.Session
....
// Locate the button with a css selector
var webElement := session.FindElement(CSS_Selector, '#redButton')
// Wait for the button to be red
webElement.WaitForCondition(ButtonIsRed, 10)
```